# What does "It doesn’t work for references that are members of objects" means in GotW #88?

Tags: c++, gotw

[Herb Sutter](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/):

> Effective Concurrency: Use Lock Hierarchies to Avoid DeadlockEffective
>   Concurrency: Break Amdahl’s Law! » GotW #88: A Candidate For the “Most
>   Important const” 2008-01-01 by Herb Sutter A friend recently asked me
>   whether Example 1 below is legal, and if so what it means. It led to a
>   nice discussion I thought I’d post here. Since it was in close to GotW
>   style already, I thought I’d do another honorary one after all these
>   years… no, I have not made a New Year’s Resolution to resume writing
>   regular GotWs. :-)
>
> JG Questions Q1: Is the following code legal C++?
>
> ```
> // Example 1
>
> string f() { return "abc"; }
>
> void g() {
> const string& s = f();
>   cout << s << endl;    // can we still use the "temporary" object?
> }
> ```
>
> A1: Yes. This is a C++ feature… the code is valid and does exactly
>   what it appears to do.
>
> Normally, a temporary object lasts only until the end of the full
>   expression in which it appears. However, C++ deliberately specifies
>   that binding a temporary object to a reference to const on the stack
>   lengthens the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the
>   reference itself, and thus avoids what would otherwise be a common
>   dangling-reference error. In the example above, the temporary returned
>   by f() lives until the closing curly brace. (Note this only applies to
>   stack-based references. **It doesn’t work for references that are
>   members of objects**.)

Originally, I think the final sentence means:

```
class A 
{
public:
    int x;
    A(const int& x_)
    {
        x = x_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a(1); // assign lvalue to const int&
    std::cout << a.x;
}
```

However, it works fine apparently.

So, what "does It doesn’t work for references that are members of objects" means?

Comment: isn't what Sutter is referring to regarding if the member is a reference? e.g. `int& x;` You've defined it `x` to be a plain member

Comment: That member isn't a reference, but it might "apparently" work fine even if it were, due to the wonders of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo the way I evoke `A a(1)` is UB? can you express in detail? thanks in advance.

Comment: @czxyl It's not undefined, because your member is not a reference. But you can't tell from observing a program's execution that it *isn't* undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that if you do something like this:

```
string f() { return "abc"; }

struct foo {
  string const & _s;
  foo() : _s(f()) {}
};
```

It won't extend the life of the temporary returned from `f`. And the reference `_s` will dangle.

Extending the lifetime of temporaries is a property of references with automatic storage duration. I.e. local variables in function scope.